# Conditional UPDATE MariaDB (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, mariadb

Code:

```
UPDATE COMPANY SET id='21' 
WHERE id='20';
```

Error:

> SQLException: Duplicate entry '21' for key 'PRIMARY'

I want to UPDATE the primary key field in this case it's called 'id' to another value but if the value exists already it throws the error above. How would I do a conditional UPDATE based on if the 'id' doesn't exist in the COMPANY table already, to avoid throwing that error using MariaDB syntax.

NOTE:
I am NOT talking about doing a conditional INSERT that uses "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" as shown below.

```
INSERT INTO COMPANY(id,first,last,age)
VALUES('1','Tim','Jones','70')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id='1';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`UPDATE IGNORE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/ignore/):

```
UPDATE IGNORE COMPANY 
SET id='21' 
WHERE id = '20'
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=616137edfae39afe85de27c8ac2d496d).

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of values already in the table:

```
UPDATE COMPANY C CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
        FROM COMPANY
        WHERE id = 21
       ) CC
    SET c.id = 21
    WHERE id = 20 AND cnt = 0;
```

Note:  In most databases, you would use `NOT EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause, but MySQL/MariaDB doesn't support references to the table being updated.